# jQuery increment and decrement button to append the applied value to a number

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, increment, decrement

So I want something like this:

[image]

As you can see, there's a `+` and `-` button, to which if clicked, they show respective values appended at `No. of Units`.

All in all, what I want is:

- for example, if I clicked the `+` four times, it will show `12+4` (the `+4` part with green color)
- and if I clicked the `-` six times, it will then show `12-2` (the `-2` part with red color),
- and if I clicked the `-` another ten times, it will stop at the value `12-12` and prompt/alert `Do you really want to delete this load?` (same function as the `x` button at the rightmost).

The problem you see is, the adding of increment values works (if I click the `+` many times), but if I decrement it, it would only stop at `0` and alternates between `0` and `1` (the operationg used is still `+` and not `-` though), and not to the maximum default value (which in the picture above, is `12`).

Also, if I clicked a decrement button first, it will only stop at `0` and the same case, it alternates between `0` and `1`.

Why is this? Sorry, I was not able to commit the previous two iterations of this code but both have issues too (the first one works but it appends a `-n` value, thus `12--1` would appear, the second one would bypass the `def` value limit, it would reach `12-14` and so on). I am at a loss here already, so I would like some help. This is my jQuery code below.

**PS. I'm constructing the rows through a jQuery `DataTables`, so I can't show the code that adds the rows because it is not too relevant.**

**PS(2). Here's the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/anobilisgorse/dydup32v/7/) implementation of the above.**

**PS(3). It would be very appreciated if you modify the code below to your liking, as log as it FOLLOWS SUIT the THREE USE CASES STATED ABOVE. Thank you so much.**

### jQuery

```
// For increment and decrement no. of units
var def = $('#costcenter_data tr').find('td:nth-child(2)').html(); // default value or the "12" in the example
var out = def;

// Increment button
$('.btn.btn-xs.btn-primary.add-unit').click(function(e){
    var count = $('#costcenter_data tr').find('td:nth-child(2)');
    var value = parseInt(count.data('change_value'));
    var clicked;

    if (isNaN(value) && isNaN(prev)) {
        value = 1;
        count.data('clicked', "+")
    } else {
        value++;
    }
    var prev = count.data('clicked');
    if (prev != "+") {
        clicked = "-";
    } else {
        clicked = prev;
    }

    $('#costcenter_data tr').find('td:nth-child(2)').html(out+clicked+value);
    count.data('change_value', value);
    count.data('clicked', "+");
});

// Decrement button
$('.btn.btn-xs.btn-warning.remove-unit').click(function(e){
    var count = $('#costcenter_data tr').find('td:nth-child(2)');
    var value = parseInt(count.data('change_value'));
    var clicked;

    if (isNaN(value) && isNaN(prev)) {
        value = 1;
        count.data('clicked', "-")
    } else if ((value-1) < 0) {
        value--;
        value = Math.abs(value);

        if (value == parseInt(def)) {
            alert("Delete prompt here");
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        value--;
        clicked = count.data('clicked');
    }
    var prev = count.data('clicked');
    if (prev != "-") {
        clicked = "+";
    } else {
        clicked = prev;
    }

    $('#costcenter_data tr').find('td:nth-child(2)').html(out+clicked+value);
    count.data('change_value', value);
});
```

Comment: Why do you use `Math.abs` ? Before you have decremented your value to `-1` and `Math.abs` will turn it to positive `1`. I guess this condition will invoke every time when value is negative, thats why your values always `0` or `1`

Comment: Oh yeah, thanks for that @t1m0n. But I'm very confused now because I haven't committed the two previous iterations of this code. The first one was a working one but it appends another `-` because the value goes negative, so it goes `12--1`. The second one; the decrement would bypass the default value (12) and goes into a limitless number. A little help pls? Setting up a fiddle.

Comment: Would be great to see fiddle.

Comment: Done @t1m0n. I edited it already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've looked at your fiddle, make some changes in `if` statements, seems like its working now - https://jsfiddle.net/oscsz4wt/.

I've add default `clicked` value so it could be accessible from the beginning and changed `if` logic. Also `clicked` may be renamed to `scope` or something like this, so it would be more clear I think.

```
// For increment and decrement no. of units
var def = $('#costcenter_data tr').find('td:nth-child(2)').html();
var out = def;
$('.btn.btn-xs.btn-primary.add-unit').click(function(e) {
  var count = $('#costcenter_data tr').find('td:nth-child(2)');
  var value = parseInt(count.data('change_value'));
  var clicked = count.data('clicked') || '+';

  // If no value
  if (isNaN(value) && isNaN(prev)) {
    value = 1;
    count.data('clicked', "+")
  // If value is positive - increase number
  } else if (value > 0 && clicked == '+') {
    value++;
  // If value is negative - decrease number
  } else if (value > 0 && clicked == '-') {
    value--;
  // If value is 0 - increase number and change scope to '+'
  } else if (value == 0) {
    value++;
    count.data('clicked', '+');
  }
  var prev = count.data('clicked');
  if (prev != "+") {
    clicked = "-";
  } else {
    clicked = prev;
  }

  $('#costcenter_data tr').find('td:nth-child(2)').html(out + clicked + value);
  count.data('change_value', value);
});
$('.btn.btn-xs.btn-warning.remove-unit').click(function(e) {
  var count = $('#costcenter_data tr').find('td:nth-child(2)');
  var value = parseInt(count.data('change_value'));
  var clicked = count.data('clicked') || '-';

  // If no value
  if (isNaN(value) && isNaN(prev)) {
    value = 1;
    count.data('clicked', "-")
  // If value is positive and we are in '+' scope decrease number
  } else if (value > 0 && clicked == '+') {
    value--;
  // If value is positive and we are in '-' scope increase number
  } else if (value > 0 && clicked == '-') {
    value++;
  // If value is 0 - increase number and change scope to '-'
  } else if (value == 0) {
    value++;
    count.data('clicked', '-');
  }

  if (value == parseInt(def) && clicked == '-') {
    alert("Delete prompt here");
    return false;
  }

  var prev = count.data('clicked');

  if (prev != "-") {
    clicked = "+";
  } else {
    clicked = prev;
  }

  $('#costcenter_data tr').find('td:nth-child(2)').html(out + clicked + value);
  count.data('change_value', value);
});
```